# How to build string that contains RTL(Hebrew) word in the middle?

Tags: c#, date-format, rtl-language

I've tried to create a string that contains a month in the middle of the date for example:

2020 **במרץ** 30

This word I want to locate in the middle: **'במרץ'**

I know that I can create a label or textbox and located where I want it. but I want to find a solution to this problem.

tried working with StringBuilder but without success

`dateBuilder = stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0} {1} {2}", year, month, day).ToString();`

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string monthName = new DateTime(year, month, day).ToString("MMMM", new CultureInfo("he-IL"));
dateBuilder = stringBuilder.AppendFormat(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", day, monthName, year)).ToString();
```

[image]